# Question about what happens to target in Keras imagedatagenerator.flow(image, target)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My image has foreground and background, and my target is the pixelwise classification of my image (0s and 1s). I want to use the ImageDataGenerator to shear / zoomin / flip these image - target pairs so I have more training data. If I do imagedatagenerator.flow(image, target), does my target get sheared / zoomed-in in the same way as the image? If samplewise center is true, does the target value get centred too? Thank you!

Comment: explain your question clearly, preferably with the part of code and error.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` is used to generate the images from the given image by specified specifications of the target images. Example you can perform flip/shear/zoom/change in heights/width to get the images.

Get the specification of the target image and feed them to ImageDataGenerator library to generate required type of image.

Below sample code may help you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('2.jpeg')
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,
                                                          width_shift_range=0.2,
                                                          height_shift_range=0.2,
                                                          rescale=1./255,
                                                          shear_range=0.2,
                                                          zoom_range=0.2,
                                                          horizontal_flip=True,
                                                          fill_mode='nearest')
image.getpixel
image_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
image_array = image_array.reshape((1,) + image_array.shape)
count = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(image_new, batch_size=1, save_to_dir ='images_gen' , save_prefix='cat', save_format='jpeg'):
  count +=1
  if count==10:
    break
```

#show the input image

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image = plt.imread('2.jpeg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#show the image after ImageDataGenerator

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image = plt.imread('images_gen/cat_0_2229.jpeg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]